# Scheduling multiple dependent ETL in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-functions, airflow, etl, apache-beam, dataflow

I have written different ETL pipelines using apache beam in python in gcp dataflow vm. Now how can we schedule those if one is dependent on others using cloud function and scheduler/ or Airflow?

Comment: You seem to be asking multiple questions. Please try to ask a specific question or explain  your current system in a better way by providing diagram's or examples. Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cloud workflow](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/quickstart-console) to achieve this.

In the principle, here the flow to perform

- Make a HTTP call to run your dataflow.
- The answer provide you a job_id
- make a loop

  - sleep 1 minute (for example)
  - get the job status with the job_id
  - if still running, continue. If not exit the loop
- Go to the next ETL job.

You can use [subworflow](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/creating-using-subworkflow) to mutualize the loop part to wait the end of the dataflow pipeline.

Let me know if you need more guidance to implement this.